# Is it posible making a cross-domain request from a https-site to a http-site?

Tags: javascript, http, https, cross-domain

I am trying to add a view-counter for my own hexo blog which is hosted on github.[my blog](https://lizterminator.github.io) 
I have made a counter app on SAE. But when i add my JavaScript code on my blog(https) to use the counter(http), cross-domain error come out. Besides, when i use http to visit my blog, it seems allright. JavaScript code like this:
`$.ajax({
    type:get,
    url:xxxxx,
    success:function(msg){
        writeDom(msg);
    }
})`

Besides, I have add `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` in my counter in SAE.
if it posible, what can i do? 
You can hit F12 in Chrome to see the error. But if you visit my site with http, there is no error anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

`https://lizterminator.sinaapp.com/`; SAE support https request.

or

Just use `http` to visit your blog.

Answer (score 0):

No, by default modern browsers do not support this for security reasons. You can manually disable this when you run Chrome, but that's obviously not a scalable solution.

Comment: Can jsonP or some other cross-domain solutions solve this problem?

Comment: No, crossing http to https boundaries at the browser / ajax level is explicitly denied. Best advice is to find a counter that has an https endpoint.

Comment: I have moved my counter to a https endpoint, but why can my site visit this https counter via http. I mean if i open my site without https, it can also access my https counter.